# calling scala class in a different file

Tags: java, scala, oop, inheritance

I am trying to call the "DefaultFaqActionHandlerClass" in another class called "DefaultFaqActionHandler". I  have tried using extend but i am not too familiar with Scala so i am having an issue doing that. Ideally, the "DefaultFaqActionHandlerClass" would be the base class with then "DefaultFaqActionHandler" as the derived class. please help.

this is what i have tried, but its throwing an error

```
class DefaultFaqActionHandler extends DefaultFaqActionHandlerClass with ActionTypeHandler {


  val intentResponse: IntentResponse
  val actionTypeRequest: ActionTypeRequest
  implicit val clientPlatform: ClientPlatform


  handleActionType(intentResponse, actionTypeRequest)(clientPlatform : ClientPlatform)

}
```

this is the class i will like inherit from.

```
class DefaultFaqActionHandlerClass  extends ActionTypeHandler{

  override def handleActionType(intentResponse: IntentResponse,
                                actionTypeRequest: ActionTypeRequest)(implicit clientPlatform: ClientPlatform): ActionTypeResponse = {

    ActionTypeResponse(
      responseData = FaqMessageTemplate.getFulfillmentMessage(
        intentName = actionTypeRequest.intentName,
        fulfillmentText = actionTypeRequest.intentFulfillmentText,
        intentParameters = actionTypeRequest.intentParameters,
        userToken = actionTypeRequest.userToken,
        accessToken = actionTypeRequest.accessToken,
        correlationId = Some(actionTypeRequest.correlationId)
      ),
      conversationContext = intentResponse.conversationContext
    )

  }
```

I am getting error...

Error:(11, 8) class DefaultFaqActionHandler needs to be abstract,

Answer (score 2):

Your class `DefaultFaqActionHandler` introduces new abstract members:

```
  val intentResponse: IntentResponse
  val actionTypeRequest: ActionTypeRequest
  implicit val clientPlatform: ClientPlatform
```

It needs to provide implementation for those or declare itself to be `abstract class` or `trait`. These are the rules in Scala or Java - you can't have abstract members in a non-abstract class. Abstract simply means you can't create an instance of it without implementing the abstract members.

In your case it doesn't matter if these two classes declared in the same or different files.

If these abstract members are already implemented in `ActionTypeHandler` or other parent classes simply don't include them in your class or provide full implementation of those.